# Google Visualization Geomap showZoomout

Tags: zooming, google-visualization, geomap

I can't get the zoomout option enabled for my Google Visualization Geomap.. I'm trying to enable it when the user has clicked on a region.. This is my code:

```js
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['geochart']});

var width, height, selectedRegion, resolution;

window.onload = function(){
    width = 556;
    height = 400;
    selectedRegion = 'world';
    resolution = 'subcontinents';
};

function drawVisualization() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    data.addColumn('string', 'Region');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Distributors');
    data.addRows([
    [{v:"005", f:"South America"}, 0],
    [{v:"011", f:"Western Africa"}, 46],
    [{v:"013", f:"Central America"}, 299],
    [{v:"014", f:"Eastern Africa"}, 63.9],
    [{v:"015", f:"Northern Africa"}, 255.7],
    [{v:"017", f:"Middle Africa"}, 21.4],
    [{v:"018", f:"Southern Africa"}, 244.5],
    [{v:"029", f:"Caribbean"}, 76.5],
    [{v:"030", f:"Eastern Asia"}, 5712.9],
    [{v:"034", f:"Southern Asia"}, 1275.1],
    [{v:"035", f:"South-Eastern Asia"}, 639.2],
    [{v:"039", f:"Southern Europe"}, 777.8],
    [{v:"053", f:"Australia and New Zealand"}, 272],
    [{v:"054", f:"Melanesia"}, 6.3],
    [{v:"057", f:"Micronesia"}, 0],
    [{v:"061", f:"Polynesia"}, 0],
    [{v:"143", f:"Central Asia"}, 0],
    [{v:"145", f:"Western Asia"}, 0],
    [{v:"150", f:"Europe"}, 0],
    [{v:"151", f:"Eastern Europe"}, 0],
    [{v:"154", f:"Northern Europe"}, 0],
    [{v:"155", f:"Western Europe"}, 0]

    ]);


    var options = {
        displayMode: 'regions',
        enableRegionInteractivity: 'true',
        resolution: resolution,
        region: selectedRegion,
        height: height,
        width: width
    };

    var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));

    google.visualization.events.addListener(geochart, 'regionClick', function(e) { 
        var clickedRegion = e['region'];

        options.region = clickedRegion;
        options.resolution = "country";     

        options.showZoomOut = true;

        geochart.draw(data, options);   
    });

geochart.draw(data, options);
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

Could someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong? The zoom out button is not showing up..

Comment: GeoCharts don't have a `showZoomOut` option, so setting it to `true` won't accomplish anything.

Comment: I got so excited when I saw this because I thought that it would be possible to create an interactive map that zoomed in/out with interaction using default options, but then I saw @asgallant's comment and knew it is too good to be true. You can do zoom in/zoom out with custom functions, but it requires creating a custom handler to zoom out/in.